# Copy files off FreeBSD

Tags: usb, freebsd, fat32, cp, bsd

I have a FreeBSD machine that I have to copy everything off the drive. The fielsystem is UFS and not readable by any other operating system. (great...)

I have a USB flash drive (FAT32) I need to copy everything to from the SATA in the bsd machine.

I looked up cp commands, and got it to partially work, but it seems to copy to the wrong directory. I cannot find out the "name" of the USB drive, and if it can even copy to it.

Comment: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/

Comment: @sergey serverfault.com ? Surely you mean unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3):

The USB drive will be mapped as a SCSI *Direct Access* device - i.e., /dev/da**

If it is the only SCSI direct access device in the system (which is likely) it will be /dev/da0

Typing: `ls /dev/da*` should confirm this.  If it is the only device you should see `/dev/da0 /dev/da0s1` returned.

You would then need to mount that device in order to access it:

```
# mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0s1 /mnt
```

(`s1` is the first 'slice' or partition on the disk)

You can then copy the data with `cp <whatever> /mnt`

When you have finished, and **before you unplug the USB device** you **must** unmount the device:

```
# umount /mnt
```

If you don't you risk data corruption on the USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD you first need to mount your USB-drive.
(See `man mount`). As I remember `mount 'what' 'where'`
For example: `mount /dev/ad10f1 /mnt/mydisk`

Use `mount -t msdos /dev/da0s1 /mnt/mydisk`     (where da0s1 is your usb-drive)
Then use `cp` command

Or you can install Samba-server and you'll be able to work with UFS-system in Windows.

Comment: FreeBSD maps the USB to SCSI Direct access (/dev/da*)